# Read time increases by 1ms for every 100 rows

Tags: cassandra

I am stuck with this issue for almost a week now. I would like to get your suggestions and help with this. I have been getting read latency problems for simple table too. I just created simple table with 4k rows and when I read 500 rows it is fetching in 5ms but if I increase 1000 it gets ~10ms if take 4k it gets around 50ms. I tried checking stats, network, iostat, tpstats, heap but couldn't get a clue of what the issue is. Could anyone help me in what more i need to do resolve this high priority issue assigned to me. Thank you very much in advance.

```
Tracing session: b4287090-0ea5-11e5-a9f9-bbcaf44e5ebc

 activity                                                                                                                    | timestamp                  | source        | source_elapsed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------
                                                                                                          Execute CQL3 query | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.961000 | 10.65.133.202 |              0
                                                 Parsing select * from location_eligibility_by_type12; [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.961000 | 10.65.133.202 |             33
                                                                                   Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.962000 | 10.65.133.202 |             62
                                                                             Computing ranges to query [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.962000 | 10.65.133.202 |            101
 Submitting range requests on 1537 ranges with a concurrency of 1537 (1235.85 rows per range expected) [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.962000 | 10.65.133.202 |            314
                                            Submitted 1 concurrent range requests covering 1537 ranges [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.968000 | 10.65.133.202 |           6960
       Executing seq scan across 1 sstables for [min(-9223372036854775808), min(-9223372036854775808)] [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2015-06-09 07:47:35.968000 | 10.65.133.202 |           7033
                                                                 Read 4007 live and 0 tombstoned cells [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2015-06-09 07:47:36.045000 | 10.65.133.202 |          84055
                                                                          Scanned 1 rows and matched 1 [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2015-06-09 07:47:36.046000 | 10.65.133.202 |          84109
                                                                                                            Request complete | 2015-06-09 07:47:36.052498 | 10.65.133.202 |          91498
```

Comment: Can you post the actual cql query?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23  Thanks for replying. Its simple query.
    select * from table;
I even tried query with a where condition on partition key.
table has 3 simple columns(type, eligibile, location ) with typeid as primary key.    All gave read latency as i increase limit in query. only till 500rows i get below 10ms.  i am completely confused on where it can be issue.

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking why it takes longer to return a larger amount of data than smaller amounts of data?

Comment: @RussS I mean i am just reading 4000 rows. its below 10ms in other environments but here its taking almost 20 ms.. are you saying that its normal to have 20ms for 3000 to 4000 rows?  i tried in diff environments but i all got below 10ms.  please let me know if i am making wrong assumptions here. thanks.

Comment: So am I to understand that your primary key definition looks like `PRIMARY KEY (typeid)`?  Do you have any clustering columns?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 yeap. type id is the primary key. and i didn't kept any clustering column. this is a test table i created. actual tables have clustering columns but they are giving far more time to read. so i just tried with simple tables but latency is going upto 30-40ms for 3k simple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting lots of rows in Cassandra often takes unpredictably long since the query will be routed to more machines.

It's best to avoid such schemas if you need high read performance. A better approach is to store data in a single row and spread the load between nodes by having a higher replication factor. Wide rows are generally preferable: http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/cassandra-summit-2014-39677149